# delete an item inside an array in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection called `Subject` and inside it a document called `"game name"` that is structured like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5234676432",
    "name": "game name",
    "questions": [
        {
            "_id": "12345",
            "question": "question",
            "answer1": "1",
            "answer2": "2",
            "answer3": "3",
            "answer4": "4",
            "correctAns": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": "56789",
            "question": "question2",
            "answer1": "1",
            "answer2": "2",
            "answer3": "3",
            "answer4": "4",
            "correctAns": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is to delete the question that the user clicks on (let's say he chose the one with the id of `"12345"`).

I tried doing that using:

`Subject.update({ name: game }, { $pull: { questions: { _id: questionToDelete } } });`

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Because you are pulling the id of the question, not the question itself which is different. I recommend you to redesign your schema.

Comment: Can you please provide the correct sample data. It seems wrong data.

Comment: You said your collection name is, ```game name```. But your query has ```Subject``` as your collection

Comment: @avivLo then how can I pull the question itself? this doesn't pull the id either.

Comment: @Aravind I just realized I wrote a collection instead of a document sorry. "Game name" is the record "Subject" is the collection.

Comment: I need to see your query

Comment: It's ok @keren rejwan . Please try the below answer. Hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would work for your problem.

```
Subject.update({name: "game name"}, 
      {$pull: {"questions": {"_id.$oid": "12345"}}}, 
      {multi: true});
```

Try once.